# Read the docs not updating with new files

Tags: read-the-docs

I'm having an issue where ReadTheDocs doesn't appear to be updating with new documentation files. Specifically, we added these files (everything d3 related here) but in ReadTheDocs they don't appear (see [this][4]); What I'd expect to see is this:

[Here's a screenshot of the correctly built docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CyrB.png)

Note the "Empirical D3 Wrapper" link, which is in the docs when built locally using "make html" but not evident when built on ReadTheDocs.

There aren't any errors in the build log that I can find, and I've tested building locally with an identical version of Sphinx to what ReadTheDocs uses.

I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this--Suggestions?

Comment: I am having similar problems, did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not--we've had a ton of issues working with autodocumenting c++ as it is and are considering moving away from sphinx/RTD entirely.