# Read the docs only import links and not the contents in it

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am very new to read the docs. I have a documentation folder **docs** in my
github repo created using Sphinx in my local machine. I tried to link the docs to *Read the Docs*.

From settings of the repo I added the read the docs service.

From *Read the Docs* website I imported the project.

But, the documentation in read the docs only shows the front page of `index.html` file. When I click any links all are empty. However, in my local machine all the links are text in it.

My github repo is  this: [github repo](https://github.com/bhishanpdl/PSF_Creation_for_PHOSIM)

My ReadTheDocs link is : [readthedocs docs](http://psf-creation-for-phosim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

**File Structure**

- docs

  - html
  - rst
    ** conf.py
  - source
  - Makefile
- src

**The main page of index.html**

[image: The main page of index.html]

**In my machine when I click first link it has contents**

[image]

**In readthedocs website when I click first link it is EMPTY**

[image]

Note that the whole repo is same in both github website and my local machine.
All the files in computer are uploaded in github, but still readthedocs only can not find the documentation.

**Question: How can we show the contents of links in ReadTheDocs ?**

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a way to fix the problem or RTD only shows the front page?

**Simple Test:**
We can download the repo (5Mb) and run index.html which shows contents inside a0_interpolate_flux link, but if we click the same link in readthedocs given above it does not show any docstring contents.

**Update**
I have googled a lot and also tried read the docs website, but to no avail. I wonder how the same HTML page opens differently in local machine and readthedocs webhost?

Some related links are following:

[[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029181/read-the-docs-not-updating-with-new-files?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029181/read-the-docs-not-updating-with-new-files?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell RTD to install your package. See RTD FAQ [My project isn’t building with autodoc](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#my-project-isn-t-building-with-autodoc).

If you look at your RTD [build history](http://readthedocs.org/projects/psf-creation-for-phosim/builds/5741913/), and expand the third bar, you will see the import errors.

To fix it:

1. Configure the RTD Admin to use a virtual environment and install your package, using a `requirements.txt` file.
2. Create a `requirements.txt` file and push it to your repo, specifying your project's requirements, itself included.

Comment: Thanks, however, I looked at build history it says build completed with green highlight, I can see no errors.

Comment: I will follow the instructions from admin tab of readthedocs and will update the question if I still get the error, Thanks Steve.

Comment: @BhishanPoudel as, I said before you need to *expand the third bar* to see the import errors. Builds can complete *with errors*. To fix it, you need to do *both* 1 and 2 in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the update, however, whatever I tried RTD fails, I uploaded requirements.txt with all required libraries, still it fails.

Comment: Why does it fail? What is the error message when you expand the third bar, as I mentioned previously?

Comment: Here RTD is successful to import the **docs** from Github. But the problem is when I click the links it opens empty links, nothing is there except the module name. However, If i download the **docs** folder form Github to my laptop and open docs/html/index.html and I click the links to the modules it opens all the docstrings. I have uploaded the pictures above in the question.

Comment: I have also uploaded **requirements.txt** file in main repo and gave the paths in admin section of RTD. RTD has no compilation errors but only shows the front page of index.html. when i click any link, nothing is there.

Comment: Relevant locations are docs/rst/conf.py   and docs/Makefile and docs/html/index.html

Comment: Visit: http://readthedocs.org/projects/psf-creation-for-phosim/builds/5751842/ Then click the grey bars of any command to expand the log for that command. In this case, the fifth grey bar reveals errors and a stacktrace with several import errors that you will need to remedy. Other grey bars indicate similar issues. For your local docs, your package is installed correctly and is importable, so of course docs build correctly. Now you must make it reproducible on RTD. Suggest reproducing the install and docs build locally in a clean separate virtual environment first to save time.

Comment: Apologies for bugging, I tried to solve the bugs, in the RTD logsfile it says module not found, but in the github all the modules are there. If you can graciously spare some time, will you suggest what should I change in ADMIN Advanced Settings of RTD ? So that I can solve this issue. This issue is taking A LOT of my time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I again updated sphinx directories, docs/source/conf.py; docs/Makefile; docs/build/html/index.html; and all the scripts are in REPO/psf_creation

Comment: And it still fails.

Comment: As I suggested previously, reproduce the install and docs build of your package locally in a clean separate virtual environment to save time instead of thrashing around with RTD. Use `pip install -r requirements.txt`, which mimics RTD when it installs a project and its requirements. If none of that helps, I suggest learning from an a known working project. Fork and clone Pyramid https://github.com/pylons/pyramid. Set up a project on RTD to build its docs. The requirements file is named `rtd.txt` and uses `pip install -e .[docs]` to install the docs requirements in `setup.py`.