# read-the-docs: ImportError despite dependency being set in setup.py

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

Consider [this build error](https://readthedocs.org/projects/jyotisha/builds/5895417/):
I see lines like: `ImportError: No module named swisseph` and `invalid signature for automodule (u'jyotisha\n      :members:')`. My [setup.py](https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/jyotisha/blob/8f52d22bcaab4bf995ac37399a9f135e81e9d422/setup.py) does include pyswisseph as a dependency already.. What's a good fix?

PS: My [local sphinx build](https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/jyotisha/tree/master/docs/build/html) seems fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/45316259/2214933

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @steve-piercy's tip and the [FAQ](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#my-project-isn-t-building-with-autodoc), I was able to get past this error - I just needed to to enable the virtualenv feature in the Admin page of my project.

The install then fails for another (as yet [undebugged reason](https://readthedocs.org/projects/jyotisha/builds/5896921/)) - but that's separate.